# Error individual price when maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart are exceced

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, price

I set max qty allowed in the shopping cart to 3 products but when I add more than 3 products to cart, the individual prices reduce.
Example product priced at 15 when you add more that 3 the price shows as 5 each.

I don't have any tier price or cart promotion there, any solution?